# ¿Cómo resolver nombres de dominio para red locales?

Tags: dns, dominio, networking

Estoy implementando en un servidor local un `helpdesk` y me gustaria que mis usuarios ingresaran de una manera mas sencilla y directa que no sea `192.168.1.1/helpdesk` (cabe destacar que no lo puedo subir a un hosting, debe ser en la `LAN`.)

Comment: Debes instalar un servidor de DNS local, o quizá el router te permita asignar nombres de domino a tus pcs locales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías tener un par de soluciones para el problema:

1. Configurar un DNS local para que sea él el que resuelva la ruta desde la url solicitada por el navegador a la IP del servidor de destino.
2. Configurar una IP pública en tu router que sea accesible desde internet y redirigir el tráfico de esa IP a tu servidor y asociar un dominio público con esa IP. Esta opción solo es válida si no hay riesgo por hacer al servidor accesible desde internet.

Comment: Seguramente si me iba a funcionar configurando los DNS, pero lo que hice fue crear un acceso directo a traves de un icono en el escritorio y problema resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

cambia el C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host y coloca esto

```
192.168.1.1 helpdesk
```

Comment: Estimado, esto solo funciona para la misma computadora que contiene el servidor. Terceros no pueden acceder a los dominios registrados manualmente en su sistema por este método, a menos que lo haga en todas las computadoras "windows" de la red local. (aun asi para otro tipo de dispositivos tendrá que usar otros métodos)

Comment: si exacto esa solución, solo funciona para una misma pc

Comment: tienes que hacer lo que te recomienda @ArieCwHat